# Homepage redirect to different location not found

Tags: wordpress

Please help. I just copy WordPress on my localhost which is I am about to install, but I can't go to the installation menu. When I go to the link that has a port it redirects and go to no port and not showing my installation.

My link: http://192.168.10.50:8282/headoffice/dueksam/

Redirected here: http://192.168.10.50/headoffice/dueksam/

but I can access the `readme.html` file inside the WordPress folder.

DBName, username, and password are set and correct.
My `DB_HOST` is set to `localhost`.

Comment: Overwrite your site_url , home_url settings of db or define it in wp-config.php file to localhost.

Answer (score -1):

You should correct the `.htaccess` file and update permalink menu to update all menu and links.